# Not able to echo POST paramenters sent in ajax, inside PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am sending two parameters inside the send method to index.php. But the PHP returns an error "Undefined index". *echo $_POST['fname'];*

```
submit.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "index.php", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        var result = xhr.responseText;
        console.log(result);
      }
    }
    xhr.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to send form data through Ajax, you have to specify the content type of the request. In you case it will be `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

So your code will be:

```
submit.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); 
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "index.php", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      var result = xhr.responseText;
      console.log(result);
    }
  }
  xhr.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
});
```